# wireless networking

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wpa-supplicant

When I connect my laptop to a **wpa2** secured router, using **[wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/)** I don't have any connection problems.

**BUT** when I connect with the following command-line command ( as outlined [here](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) )

**UPDATED:**

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhcpd wlan0
```

My connection is unstable, sometimes working sometimes not, indicated by the following output:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (64.233.179.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=190 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=196 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=184 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=172 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.179.104: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=196 ms
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=210 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=181 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=168 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=168 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=171 ms
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=171 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=164 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=181 ms
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=187 ms 
64 bytes from cpt01s01-in-f104.1e100.net (64.233.179.104): icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=192 ms
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 15 received, 40% packet loss, time 28231ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 164.443/182.621/210.508/12.774 ms
```

My `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
network={
    ssid="1010011010"
    #psk="------------"
    psk=------------------------------------------
}
```

`dhcpcd wlan0`

```
$ sudo dhcpcd wlan0 
dhcpcd[18320]: version 5.2.5 starting
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.123.102
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: acknowledged 192.168.123.102 from 192.168.123.254
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: checking for 192.168.123.102
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: carrier lost
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: carrier acquired
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.123.102
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: acknowledged 192.168.123.102 from 192.168.123.254
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: checking for 192.168.123.102
dhcpcd[18320]: wlan0: leased 192.168.123.102 for 86400 seconds
dhcpcd: wlan0: MTU set to 1500
dhcpcd[18320]: forked to background, child pid 18377
```

`ifconfig`

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:AF:78:D4:AA  
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:afff:fe78:d4aa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2909 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1959355 (1.8 Mb)  TX bytes:415438 (405.7 Kb)
```

`route`

```
$ route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.123.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
default         192.168.123.254 0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: It might be helpful for you to post the contents of your wpa_supplicant.conf file.  Be sure to remove any secret information (like your network key) before posting.

Comment: `10.0.0.2` vs `192.168.0.2` - it looks like 2 different networks? It looks like somehow non-standard configuration. Would you mind to describe the architecture?

Comment: Looks like 2 successes on 10.0.0.2 and 2 fails on 192.168.0.2. Show us your ifconfig, the contents of your wpa_supplicant.conf, and describe your network

Comment: @Maciej, the `10.0.0.2` is just a ip outside of my wireless network. I replaced it with `google.com`

Comment: Did [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/wireless-networking/4528#4528) help?

Comment: nope... never solved this, just using wicd now

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that wireless signal is low, but that doesn't explain why wicd works.

Answer (score 0):

you want a `sleep 10s` before the dhcpd part at the least